# Не обновляется PhpStorm на Ubuntu

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains

Установил на Ubuntu PhpStorm. Пришло сообщение о минорном обновлении. Я нажал "обновить", скачался файл обновления, IDE перезапустилась... и версия осталась той же. PhpStorm был запущен из-под рута.

Смотрел лог, не нашёл в нём строчек, которые говорят о каких-либо ошибках в обновлении.

Как мне всё-таки обновиться?

Comment: когда заходите в `check updates` он говорит что нужно обновиться? если нет, то все обновилось

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, да, говорит. И в заголовке окна показывается старая версия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установил [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/). После этого стало возможным обновлять PhpStorm с помощью этого приложения.

Answer (score 5):

**Вступление**

В Ubuntu PhpStorm не обновляется автоматически. Для обновления необходимо сделать примерно те же действия, что и при его установке. Его необходимо скачать, распаковать в новую папку и запускать оттуда.

Для того, чтобы обновления IDE было проще выполнять, я написал [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Jekis/663648b941856ffc2c16842fe6044bf6). Это файл, который сделает за вас рутинную работу.

**Обновление**

1. На основании gist'a создайте у себя файл `update-phpstorm.sh`
2. Сделайте файл исполняемым `chmod +x update-phpstorm.sh`
3. Запустите обновление `sudo ./update-phpstorm.sh`

> Можете удалить вашу предыдущую версию PhpStorm, если она не находилась
>   в папке `/opt/phpstorm`. Это понадобится сделать только один раз. В
>   последующие обновления скрипт будет автоматически удалять предыдущую
>   версия из папки `/opt/phpstorm`.

**Пояснения к работе скрипта**

1. Скрипт скачает последнюю версию редактора.
2. Удалит старую версию. *(Настройки не пропадут, так как они хранятся в домашней директории пользователя)*
3. Распакует новую версию
4. Скачает java-агент, который исправляет [проблему горячих клавиш](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962) при русской раскладке клавиатуры.
5. Обновляет `phpstorm64.vmoptions` файл, в который прописывает запуск вышеуказанного агента и меняет параметры использования памяти. *(Если у Вас не 64-битная ОС, исправьте в скрипте имя файла `phpstorm64.vmoptions` на `phpstorm.vmoptions`)*
6. Создастся [значок программы](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_unity) для запуска.

**Запуск**

Если Вы используете Unity, то вам остаётся только открыть **Dash** и в поиске вбить **PhpStorm**.

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже нашёл решение с использованием Jetbrains Toolbox

Comment: Отметьте мой ответ правильный, если Вы так считаете, или опубликуйте свой ответ, чтобы другим людям было проще найти решение.